# I would like to make a field part of a many to many relationship

Tags: sql

I have the following table called stores

```
   id     store       zip
   1     Market 1    01569
   2     Market 2    01551
   3     Market 3    10468
   4     Market 4    10435
```

Zip code table

```
   INSERT INTO `zip_codes` (`restaurants_locations_id`, `zip`, `state`, `latitude`, `longitude`, `city`, `full_state`) VALUES
(1, '06001', 'CT', ' 41.789698', ' -72.86431', 'Avon', 'Connecticut'),
(2, '06002', 'CT', ' 41.832798', ' -72.72642', 'Bloomfield', 'Connecticut'),
(3, '06010', 'CT', ' 41.682249', ' -72.93365', 'Bristol', 'Connecticut'),
(4, '06013', 'CT', ' 41.758415', ' -72.94642', 'Burlington', 'Connecticut'),
(5, '06016', 'CT', ' 41.909097', ' -72.54393', 'Windsorville', 'Connecticut'),
(6, '06018', 'CT', ' 42.023510', ' -73.31103', 'Canaan', 'Connecticut'),
(7, '06019', 'CT', ' 41.834247', ' -72.89174', 'Canton', 'Connecticut'),
```

etc....

what I want is to create a table which will connect the zip field in the stores tables where one store will be found in several zicodes...

How would that table would look like?

Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really get what you want. Don't you already have `zip` in `zip_code_table` pointing to `zip` in `stores`? Shouldn't a Foreign Key be sufficient? Is this what you are asking for? What database are you using?

Comment: Not quite sure what you want to achieve. Please try to rephrase your question.

Comment: I am using the stores database, sometimes a stores can deliver to outside the only zicode it has assign right now, instead of only being able to assign only one zid code I would like to assign several picking them up from the database zip_codes which I am not using right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a table called Store_To_Zip_Map or whatever you want to call it.

This table only needs 2 columns: store_id and zip

Simply make a row in that table for each Store ID and Zip pairing. In the example below, stores 1 and 2 each have 2 zip codes. One of the zip codes is attached to both stores.

```
store_id    zip
1           11111
1           12222
2           12222
2           22222
```